# Como configurar un messagebox de tkinter askyesnocancel personal?

Tags: funciones, tkinter, python-3.7, messagebox

Estoy intentando configurar en tkinter un messagebox askyesnocancel que se ajuste más a la estética del programa pero no logro que la función retorne el valor que arroja la acción de hacer *click* en algún botón.
Este sería el código de la clase:

```py
class V_info(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None,title=None,msg=None,img=None,opcion=0):

        super().__init__(master,bg='#999999')        
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.msg = msg
        self.img = img
        self.opcion = opcion
        self.master.title(self.title)
        self.master.resizable(0,0)
        self.pack(expand=True,fill='both')
        self.textbtn1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.initComponents()
        self.master.geometry(placev(self.master,output=1))
        if self.opcion == 0:
            self.textbtn1.set('Aceptar')
            self.master.bind('<Return>',self.btn1clicked)
        elif self.opcion == 1:
            self.textbtn2 = tk.StringVar()
            self.textbtn3 = tk.StringVar()
            self.textbtn1.set('Cancelar')
            self.textbtn2.set('No')
            self.textbtn3.set('Si')
            self.set_yesnocancel_mode()


    def initComponents(self):

        self.ftop = tk.Frame(self,bg='#999999')
        self.ftop.pack(expand=True,fill='both',padx=(30,20),pady=20)

        tk.Label(self.ftop,image=self.img,bg='#999999').pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=5)
        tk.Label(self.ftop,text=self.msg,bg='#999999',justify=tk.LEFT).pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=5)
        self.fbtns = tk.Frame(self,bg='#999999')
        self.fbtns.pack(expand=True,fill=tk.BOTH,side=tk.BOTTOM,padx=20,pady=(0,10))
        tk.Button(self.fbtns,textvariable=self.textbtn1,bg='#CCCCCC',font=setFont('btn'),command=self.btn1clicked).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        

    def btn1clicked(self,event=None):

        self.master.destroy()
        if self.opcion == 1:
            self.choise = None
            self.event_generate('<<btnclicked>>')


    def btn2clicked(self):

        self.choise = False
        self.event_generate('<<btnclicked>>')


    def btn3clicked(self):

        self.choise = True
        self.event_generate('<<btnclicked>>')


    def set_yesnocancel_mode(self):

        tk.Button(self.fbtns,textvariable=self.textbtn2,bg='#CCCCCC',font=setFont('btn'),command=self.btn2clicked).pack(side=tk.RIGHT,padx=5)
        tk.Button(self.fbtns,textvariable=self.textbtn3,bg='#CCCCCC',font=setFont('btn'),command=self.btn3clicked).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
```

Esta es la función que crea una instancia de la clase y con la que intento capturar el valor que se 'choise' que se genera en dependencia del botón que se presione:

```py
def myasksinocancel(title=None,msg=None,master=None):

    def return_choise(event):
        print(v_info.choise) # aquí sí imprime el valor
        return v_info.choise # pero no logro que la función padre lo retorne
    if master is None:
        master = get_vmodal()
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'.\images\question.png').subsample(7)
    v_info = V_info(master,title,msg,img,opcion=1)
    v_info.bind('<<btnclicked>>',return_choise)
```

Y desde aquí arranca todo:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = tk.Tk()
    result = myasksinocancel('Atencion','Desea realizar esta operación?')
    app.mainloop()
    print(result)
```

Esto último solo una prueba para ver si logro capturar el valor en la variable `result`. Estoy intentando imitar el comportamiento de la misma función original del módulo `tkinter.messagebox` pero no lo logro por esta vía. Me dice que hay un error porque la función `myasksinocancel` no retorna ningún valor. Se me ocurre instanciar directamente la clase sin utilizar la función como intermediador pero sería muy engorroso cada vez que necesite usar esta herramienta tomar este camino tan largo. Alguien que sepa de una mejor forma de hacerlo???

Nota: `get_vmodal()`

```
def get_vmodal(master=None):

        v = tk.Toplevel()
        v.focus_set()
        v.grab_set()
        v.transient(master=master)
        return v
```

Comment: Lo que entiendo es usted que quiere de algún modo replicar el comportamiento de los cuadros de diálogo `messagebox` estándar que administra Tkinter y la respuesta al hacer clic algunos de los botones, aunque fíjese que `messagebox` maneja un comportamiento de respuesta en algunos por medio de condicionales y devuelven una cadena que representa en la acción por medio de un valor booleano entre verdadero o falso. Si aplica esto es una instancia de clase de la ventana, la acción o `command` de los botones es la función que usted ha definido, es lo que entendí, si es posible puede aclararlo?.

Comment: Si..eso mismo...deseo replicar el comportamiento de los messagebox estandar de tkinter...sobre todo pq estos no me dan opcion de personalizarlos demasiado y por razones estéticas preferiría que se parecieran más a las demás ventanas de la aplicación